# Triangles tiling on a hexagon

Tags: geometry, visual

Each number means the numbers of blue tiling surrounding the number

[image]

example

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blue-filled hexagon in below:

> [image]

How I solved this:

> First, There **had** to be blue on both triangles between the 4's. That gives us 4 blues triangles already done. The rest was obvious.

Comment: wow, you answer it very fast..  does the question is too easy ?

Comment: I believe the hex in question could be bigger to make the puzzle take some more time.

Comment: It was quite easy, but also fun.

Comment: Next time I will make bigger hexagon.

Comment: @Jamal Senjaya Looking forward to it :)