# Hexagonal minesweeper

Tags: geometry, visual

Based on a [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44604/triangles-tiling-on-a-hexagon) given to us by Jamal Senjaya I created a bigger one. Hope it is not too easy.
[image]

The number in circle means how many of adjacent triangles should be painted blue.

**EDIT**
I did not mention (I was not aware) that the puzzle has many (I hope not too many) possible solutions. There is one however that "makes more sense" - if you see it you will know that this is it. All valid solutions will earn an upvote (hopefully not only from me), but only "the one" will be accepted. The desired solution can be distinguished by the fact that the resulting image is a 4-letter word.

Comment: Are you sure there is a unique answer ? The hard part to create this kind of puzzle is to make sure there is only 1 unique answer.

Comment: There are LOTS of possible solutions. There are some variations you can make more to the center and all solutions can change a lot of the colors in the outer circle to still produce a valid coloring. So it seems really hard to find which solution you intended.

Comment: My calculations show 14,233 (!) possible solutions.

Comment: @2012rcampion Care to share them? Ah, there is a separate question for the calculations like this.

Comment: I used [`SatisfiabilityCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiabilityCount.html) which only counts the solutions, instead of returning them all.  (Getting all of them is much much slower.)

Comment: @2012rcampion Reframe it so that the unshared outer triangles are no longer used and the circles adjacent to them turn into inequality rather than equality constraints. The number of solutions will be much lower and I bet enumerating them will not be terribly slow.

Comment: Hmm, actually not as much lower as I thought. There seem to be 9449 solutions then.

Comment: ... but it takes only about 1.5 seconds to find all of them (Mma 9, PC, a year or so old but a nice fast machine when it was bought).

Comment: I still don't much fancy looking through them all to try to guess which one is "the one".

Comment: I also eliminated the variables corresponding to triangles whose colours can easily be found by hand. I ended up with 35 variables. Now that I think about it, it's not surprising that the number of solutions wasn't much lower -- the only reductions will come from the corners where you can have a choice between blue/notblue and notblue/blue.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan You are right - I did not expect teh puzzle to have so many solutions. I will figure something out to make it better.

Comment: @2012rcampion Consider answering the linked question (about counting the number of possible solutions)

Comment: Cool idea for a puzzle, I wish this was an app I could get for my phone!

Comment: [Here are all the solutions](https://gist.github.com/2012rcampion/248ff6fee3f60d244454c876419f5ca7) (cells in reading order, `x` is blue, `.` is blank)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This displays the missing verbal ingredient,
which certainly does add a nice dimension to the puzzle.

> $ \small\sf \color{black}{\text{The word is }} \normalsize\it \rlap{NICE} $
>  [image]

Began with
[Jonathan Allan’s report](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44612/18129)
of which triangles had certain values,
then considered the four-letter hint,
noticed what the third letter must be,
and defocused for the rest.

Arrows point where the goal of forming letters
suggested filled-in triangles in the top half.
Each suggestion led to a few more forced values,
until three fairly-certain letters were apparent.

> [image]

Comment: Very nice solution. This is "the one" I was thinking about. Happy to see it has been solved. I think you should mention the word explicitly in your answer - just for clarity.

Comment: Nice how the solution was constrained enough by a mathematical first stage to allow for a nonmathematical second stage. The hint was probably necessary after all.

Comment: This can't be the right answer since none of the triangles are painted blue. ;-)

Comment: Oboy, this must've been an answer to some other puzzle.
To make up for that, more than half of the triangles are now blue.

Answer (score 16):

Here is another possible solution, with a first stage that is necessary:

> Red means can't be blue in the top image and blue means must be blue, the second image is then one way to fill in the rest. [image: a solution with necessary first step]

Comment: I wish I could upvote +2 for pointing out the "necessary" part.

Comment: The "necessary" part is the easy one. After that part, you pretty much have to takes guesses due to multiple possibilities.

Comment: @stackreader Next puzzle - how many solutions does this Hexagonal Minesweeper™ have?

Comment: @JonathanAllan That would be fun actually.... but might nmke my brain hurt.

Comment: @ Jonathan Allan Just did it

Answer (score 7):

I feel like there might be many possibilities but here is mine.

> [image]

Comment: Also no blue here ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Here's my version.

> [image: Solved Puzzle]
>
>  I actually started at the top with the two 5 nodes and just worked my way around. I did the 0 nodes before messing with the surrounding nodes, then did the 1 nodes, then the other 5 nodes. Everything else was kind of random, but I didn't have to re-do anything.
>
>  Blue are "blue" nodes. I used gray to say "this can't be a node" as I went along, then left it that way when I finished.

Answer (score 4):

I made a [little program](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_-_Z6IMqDH9ME15ckc2UmpvOW8/view?usp=sharing) to demonstrate this puzzle. It is an interactive thing that you can click on and off to select "mines". I made blue the color of the safe spots, and red the color of mines. White is simply unselected:

My solution:

> [image] It is the only spots I can prove are filled in that manner.