# How many solutions does a hexagonal minesweeper have?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, geometry, visual, combinatorics

I recently posted a [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44607/hexagonal-minesweeper), which appeared to have multiple solutions:

The numbers in circles represent how many of the six adjacent triangles will be "blue" in any possible solution:

[image]

The question is: **How many**?

**Bonus challenge**: A general rule for this kind of problems allowing a person to compute the number of solutions for any given hexagonal minesweeper.

**NOTE** I do not know the answer myself - I'm asking out of pure curiosity.

Comment: At first sight the huge hexagonal almost made me jump out of my skin. I expect that would be a nice puzzle :D

Comment: @rcampion2012 has already counted these for the particular problem here, using Mathematica which has general-purpose machinery for counting solutions to this sort of problem. I expect this involves a combination of linear algebra (over the field with two elements) and brute-force searching. I would be *astonished* if there were a general rule that's practically usable by human beings without computers.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the base that won't change.
Next is to find all the possibilities for the remaining pieces.

> [image]

Here is the part that matters with update numbers in the circles

> [image]
>  There is 51 triangles left so technically $2^{51}$ possibilities without taking into accounts the numbers in circles.

Then we gotta start taking into account the numbers.

> One 1 in contact with 2 = 2 possibilities
>  One 1 in contact with 4 = 4 possibilities
>  Four 2 in contact with 3 triangles = 81 possibilities($3^4$)
>  One 2 in contact with 6 = 15 possibilities
>  Two 3 in contact with 4 = 16 possibilities ($4^2$)
>  Eight 3 in contact with 6 = ($20^8$) possibilities
>  Three 4 in contact with 6 = 3375 possibilities  ($15^3$)
>  Two 5 in contact with 6 = 36 possibilities ($6^2$)
>  So 2x4x81x15x16x36x3375x$20^8$ possibilities without taking into account sharing a triangle with another circle.
>  The next step would be to remove possibilities depending on which triangles are being shared... Which is the hard part.... Might have to use a program for that.

Comment: You're on the money, to get a mathematical count one would use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)